# PHP file can't connect to my database?

Tags: php, mysql

Okay. So my code does seem to work, but I whenever I type something into the fields and click submit, then the data should be send to the phpmyadmin database hallo123, but it doesn't seem to work since nothing happens in the database then and the database is still empty. Oh and the other similiar questions here didn't really help me so please don't flag this question. So here's the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Tabelle</title>
<form action="test.php" action="POST"/>
Tabelle1: <input type="text" name="Tabelle1"/><br/>
Tabelle2: <input type="text" name="Tabelle2"/><br/>
Tabelle3: <input type="text" name="Tabelle3"/><br/>
Tabelle4:<input type="text" name="Tabelle4"/><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Absenden"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

test.php:

```
<?php
/* Nothing to do here. 
*/
?>
<html>
<head><title>Tabelle, Mann</title></head>
<body>
<?php
include "phpfile.php";
include "htmltest.php";
$user="root";
$host="localhost";
$password=""; 
$database="hallo123"; 
$Katze="Stella";
$cxn = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database)
or die("Verbindung fehlgeschlagen");
$Tabelle1="Hund"; 
$query="SELECT * FROM Tabelle1
WHERE Tabelle2 = '$Katze'"; 
?>
```

phpfile.php:

```
<?php
$host="localhost";
$nutzer="root"; 
$passwort=""; 
$dbname="hallo123";
$cxn=mysqli_connect($host, $nutzer, $passwort, $dbname)
or die("GET LOST ;)"); 
mysqli_close($cxn);
?>
```

Comment: Can you add :
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
so we could have the error message returned from mysqli

Comment: 1) Phpmyadmin is not a database; MySQL is your actual database. 2) Your code doesn't do anything. It may successfully connect to a database, but that's it. It doesn't interact with the database beyond connecting to it. So I'm not sure what you expect to happen here.

Comment: the url does change because you are using a method get in your form. your said action="POST" which is not the same as method="post" (and I wonder what kind of results one might expect by having 2 action attributes in one form. 
You would be better by following some html/php/mysql/programming tutorials

Answer (score 2):

```
die("GET LOST ;)");
```

No don't get lost, ask your code to give you the actual error message

```
die(mysqli_connect_error());
```

That tells you what is wrong first and then it gets lost :)

To quote from the Manual

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
```

**[Reference](http://php.net/mysqli_error)**

Comment: i replaced the line with what you wrote but it doesn't show me any error. instead the url changes from localhost/php***.php into http://localhost/*****/test.php?Tabelle1=ddddd&Tabelle2=ddddd&Tabelle3=ddddd&Tabelle4=dddddd also note that I wrote these things into the fields.

Comment: The code that you gave us doesn't have any such redirect. Can you please add that in your question? Secondly can you tell us what does "not working" mean in this case? Maybe your connection is fine and your query isn't. Where are you executing the query and are you checking for any errors returned?

Comment: I'm trying to insert data from the php file into the phpmyadmin database the connectinon seems fine but the php file doesn't insert any data

Comment: The code you've provided doesn't include any attempt to insert data.

Comment: @harris but the html code does submit data to the php file so it should insert data

Comment: Why should it insert the data when there's nothing in the code that does any inserting?

Comment: @Dark Programming involves writing a lot of detailed code; very little to none of it involves "I told it to do A so it *should* do B by itself"...

Comment: @harris yes i saw it now

Answer (score 0):

You can do directly like this:- write in your phpfile.php

```
global $con;
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "hallo123");
if(!$con)
{
 echo "connection error";
}
```

and you are writing again in your test.php,don't write thier just include phpfile.php file and do what you want to do.
you have to call that connection in your file wherever you have included that phpfile.php which would be like this...

```
    $get_users=mysqli_query($con,"select column_name from table_name");

         if(mysqli_num_rows($get_users))
             {
               while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_users))
                         {
                         $users=$row['column_name'];
                         }
             }
```

just try this..